# How to change text and button image (or button) when I click

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working with angular. When I click a button, I get a dropdown with some choices. How can I change the button image or button and text when I click on it? The goal is for it to return to its original state when it is clicked again.

I leave the image here to understand better.

The button in my case will be an image.

[image]

What I want is this: I click the button and open the dropdown, in that dropdown, when I click Start, I want the image of the button to be changed (or the button) and Start to be Pause. If you do the same again, the opposite happens ... that is, if you have Pause, pressing it changes the button and Pause becomes Start.

It is possible? Can anyone help me?

**Example, my code**

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Harry_x21/pen/MWWzPEd)

**HTML**

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <img src="">
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item">Start</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Add new</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am working with angular, if anyone can help me get the solution using their resources, I really appreciate

Comment: Which button is to be shown on clicking start and pause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store the current state and toggle view using it's value.

**app.component.ts** :

```
currentState : string = 'pause'
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <!-- Image is to be shown by default -->
        <img src="1.png" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'"">
        <!-- Image is to be shown on clicking start -->
        <img src="2.png" *ngIf="currentState=='start'"">
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='pause'" (click)="currentState='start'">Start</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="currentState=='start'" (click)="currentState='pause'">Pause</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a function to onChange and do it there,

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button (change)="changeImg()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <img src="{{imgSrc}}">
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="isStarted">Start</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="!isStarted">Pause</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item">Add new</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

in ts,

```
    isStarted:boolean = false; // default to pause
    imgSrc:any;
    changeImg(){
     // We can even write the simplest code instead the below line.
     // isStarted = false ? true : false;
     isStarted = !isStarted;
     imgSrc = isStarted ? startImageSrc : pauseImageSrc; 
    }
```

hope this works, did not test :)

Comment: Thanks to try help me, best regards !